# Hide shipping address in WooCommerce email notifications for local pickup delivery

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, shipping-method

Is it possible to hide the WooCommerce shipping address of clients when they choose a local pickup delivery from email notifications?

I just hide the shipping address of my **checkout page** when local pickup is selected, however this is still present on the automatic WooCommerce email notifications and this is very confusing for the customers.

Is it possible to add a code snippet to erase it from the email template ?

Answer (score 1):

Hide shipping address from orders and email notifications for a specific shipping method:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_order_needs_shipping_address', 'local_pickup_hide_shipping_address', 10, 3 );
function local_pickup_hide_shipping_address( $needs_address, $hide, $order ) {
    // Define below the shipping method slug that hides shipping address
    $shipping_method_id = 'local_pickup'; 

    // Loop through shipping methods for the current order
    foreach ( $order->get_shipping_methods() as $shipping_method ) {
        if( $shipping_method->get_method_id() === $shipping_method_id ) {
            $needs_address = false; // Hide
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $needs_address;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

If you are using some custom shipping methods (enabled by some plugins, you need to set the correct shipping method ID slug)